Hadamard geometric mean and positivity
As part of some research, I need the following kind of statement regarding the Hadamard geometric mean of two square matrices.
Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with positive entries, and both $\mathbf{1}-A$ and $\mathbf{1}-B$ are positive definite matrices (all their eigenvalues are positive), where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the all-ones matrix $\mathbf{1}_{ij}=1$.
Is it known whether $\mathbf{1}-(A\circ B)^{\circ\frac 12}$ has to be positive definite? (The $\circ$ means Hadamard (entrywise) product, so that the matrix $(A\circ B)^{\circ\frac 12}$ has (i,j)-entry equal to $\sqrt{A_{ij}B_{ij}}$). By numerical experimentation, this seems to be valid in the $2\times 2$ case.
Any idea or counterexample would be highly appreciated.

A counterexample:
$$A=\frac1{100}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 154 & 163 \\
 154 & 1 & 9 \\
 163 & 9 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\quad
B=\frac1{100}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 9 & 163 \\
 9 & 1 & 154 \\
 163 & 154 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Thanks. So, the 3x3 case already fails...

Actually, can you tell me what is the method/idea behind the construction of such examples? Indeed, in your example $\mathbf{1}-(A\circ B)^{\circ\frac12}$ has an extremely simple eigendecomposition...

@Hexhist : I used Mathematica to numerically minimize $\det(\mathbf 1-(A\circ B)^{\circ1/2})$ given the restrictions on $A$ and $B$. The minimum turned out to be $<0$.
